# Translate sql query on Django

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I have two tables: **students** (that has all the students of a school) and **suspensions** (all the students that are suspended)

| id | name | school_grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jeff | 1 |
| 2 | Dave | 1 |
| 3 | Susan | 2 |
| 4 | Will | 2 |
| 5 | Peter | 3 |

| id | reason | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Missed class | 1 |
| 2 | Arrived 20 times late | 2 |
| 3 | Fight | 5 |

So I need to get statistics of which students of different grades are suspended.

So, my query is this.

```
    SELECT school_grade, count(school_grade) 
    FROM students JOIN suspensions ON students.id=suspensions.student_id 
    GROUP BY school_grade;
```

And this query gives me exactly what I want.

| school_grade | number of suspension |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

But I don't understand how to make this query on django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
students.objects.values("school_grade").annotate(Count("suspensions"))
```

This should work as expected